# In form submit when i am going to next page the data is not coming

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

This is my html first page in which we will fill the details

```
<div data-role="content">
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       <label for="name1">Name</label>
          <input name="name1" id="name1" value="" type="text">
   </div>
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input name="age" id="age" value="" type="text">
   </div>
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
         <input name="address" id="address" value="" type="text">
   </div>
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
         <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
         <input name="mobilet" id="mobile" value="" type="text">
   </div>
   <div data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" id="button">Submit</div>
</div>
```

Below is the second page, in which we will show the filled data, one edit button will be given which will take user to the first page again.

```
<div data-role="content" id="content2">
    <form id="form1">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <span class="field" style="padding:350px;" id="un"></span>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="age">age</label>
            <span class="field1" style="padding:350px;" id="pw"></span>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <span class="field2" style="padding:350px;" id="au"></span>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
            <span class="field3" style="padding:350px;" id="fr"></span>
        </div> 
        <div style="text-align:center;">                    
            <div data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" id="button2">Edit</div>
        </div> 
    </form>
</div>
```

in jquery:-

```
$(document).unbind('pageinit').bind('pageinit', function () {          
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        callConnection();
    });     
    $("#button2").click(function () {
        callEditConnection();
    });
});

function callConnection(){
    localStorage.setItem("user", $("#name1").val());
    localStorage.setItem("pass", $("#age").val());
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
}

function callEditConnection(){
    $("#un").val(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    $("#pw").val(localStorage.getItem("pass"));
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");       
}
```

Please help me to find out what the problem is with my code that page2 the value of page1 is not coming

Comment: when you are loading page 2,I don't see any data passed to page 2. try to set the fields value when page 2 is loaded in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code I can't see that you are passing data to page 2,
I assume that you want to show the data you entered on page 1 ,In your documnent bind method put this code

```
$("#page2").on("pageshow", function (event) {
    $("#un").text(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    $("#pw").text(localStorage.getItem("pass"));
});
```

The function will be triggered when the page will be shown.
So here we get the values from the local storage and put it in the html.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CaQB/)